# Requiring devise in rspec model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I'm using devise in my Admin model like so:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Functionally, this is working fine. But I want to have specs for my Admin class, so I start to write a spec...

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'admin'

describe Admin do
  it 'mumblemumble' do ... end
end
```

...and then when I go to run the spec, it blows up:

```
active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Admin(Table doesn't exist):Class (NoMethodError)
```

How do I require Devise so that it's available in my spec? It seems like I should be able to

```
require 'devise'
```

in either my spec or my model (preferably my model), but this doesn't fix the issue or change my stack trace. How do I require Devise so that my model has the helper method available? I'm poking around the Devise gem but I'm not finding any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I run specs with an in-memory instance of sqlite3, so all the `db:test:prepare` doesn't apply to me. In addition to requiring Devise, it must also be `setup/configured`.

So in `/spec/support/devise.rb`:

```
require 'devise'

Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
end
```

And then in spec_helper.rb:

```
Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you running these?  RSpec directly?  Or `bundle exec rake spec`?

There's this in your error: `for Admin(Table doesn't exist)` which makes me wonder if you have a database yet.  The rake task should take care of setting up your world for you.

If that doesn't help, post your `spec_helper.rb` contents too.

Here's a basic Admin model I have:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
         :trackable, :validatable
end
```

And a basic spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
end
```

Works great with vanilla generated rails app and generated devise setup.

Answer (score 1):

This error

```
undefined method `devise' for Admin(Table doesn't exist):Class (NoMethodError)
```

seems to be that you don't have the table in the db? Did you migrate the rake file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems your test database does not have the `admins` table.
Try this:

`bundle exec rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`

`db:migrate` migrates your development database, if there are any pending migrations and `db:test:prepare` clones your test database according to the development one.